# Add links inside carousel/lightbox content by each different image

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, lightbox, jcarousel

this is my question: I have a ligthbox in a carousel, and I want to show a different link when each image in the lightbox is loaded, not before.  I do this by adding a link in the html structure. But the link is different for every image, so I need to identify every image by its src atribute, and then add the link I want when that image is loaded. This is what I have, and I don´t know how to follow...

html struture:

```
            <a href="images/lightbox/yamm.jpg" class="lb_gallery"  ><img src="images/lightbox/01_thumb.png"/></a> 
            <a href="images/lightbox/blog.jpg" class="lb_gallery" ><img src="images/lightbox/02_thumb.png" /></a>
            <a href="images/lightbox/asisaden.jpg" class="lb_gallery" ><img src="images/lightbox/03_thumb.png" /></a> 
            <a href="images/lightbox/interiordetalle.jpg" class="lb_gallery"><img src="images/lightbox/04_thumb.png" /></a> 

     </div>
```

my js code:

```
    var $img = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    var src = $img.attr("src");
    if(src == 'images/lightbox/yamm.jpg') {
    $("#ui-lightbox-enlace-wrapper").append('<a href="#" target="_blank">
    Link text</a>');

    }
```

Thanks.